# Return a .zip file containing several .csv files to the browser with ZipOutputStream

Tags: java, html, http, zip

To begin with, I am well aware that a similar topic is available on Stack OverFlow, but this one does not answer my problem. That's why I'm making this post.

At the moment, my program is able to search for ".csv" files locally, according to certain criteria, to add them to a list, and then to create a file in ".zip" format, which contains all these files. This works without any problem.

Now, I want to download this ".zip" file, from a Web interface, with a button. The connection between the code and the button works, but when I open my downloaded ".zip" file, it contains only one file, and not all the ".csv" files it is supposed to contain. Where can the problem come from?

Here is my code:

```
FileOutputStream baos = new FileOutputStream("myZip.zip");
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
                        
for(String sCurrent : selectedFiles){
    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(new File(sCurrent).getName()));
    Files.copy(Paths.get(sCurrent), zos);
    zos.closeEntry();
}
zos.close();
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer so much as consolidation based on @DuncG

```
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

            for (String path : selectedFiles) {
                zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(new File(path).getName()));
                Files.copy(Paths.get(path), zos);
                zos.closeEntry();
            }
            zos.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! I just made the changes, can you tell me if my code is correct? On my side, the "zip" contains nothing at all, it is 0Kb in size.

Comment: You're not writing to the response output stream at all now. You're writing to a file..?

Comment: I don't know what to put here: response.getOutputStream().write([...]);
It doesn't allow me "zos", nor "baos".

Comment: See addition above to my 'answer'

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your answer!

I just did the test, I already have less worries, except that there is still only one ".csv" in my ".zip" file. I just did a new test, there is the same file twice, mentioned in my list of files found, before making the ".zip". However, I do not know at the moment, why it appears twice, because in my directory, it is present only once... Could this make it so that I only get one file in my ".zip", because of this duplication? Thank you.

Comment: That's it, problem solved!
To summarize, there were the errors reported by DuncG and g00se. Then, an error of duplication (I had put my loop of creation of the file ".zip" within another loop, which caused duplicates of files, which prevented the correct creation of the file ".zip", with the good number of ".csv" wished). Thanks again to all for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You are closing the ZIP after sending the response. Swap the order:

```
zos.close();
response.getOutputStream().write(baos.toByteArray());
```

It would be more efficient if you use try-with-resources to handle close, `Files.copy(Paths.get(currentFile), zos);` to transfer the files, and if you ZIP straight to the output stream because you might risk out of memory exceptions for large files:

```
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I just did the test, it remains the same... My ".zip" file contains only one csv... I really don't know what to do!

Comment: What is in 'selectedFiles'? Maybe there's just one path or the filenames are the same in different paths (you only use the *name*). No need for ```Iterator``` btw

Comment: @g00se Thank you for your feedback. When I decide to run the method through FileOutputStream instead of ByteArrayOutputStream, saving the ".zip" file directly to the desired location, it works. It is since the addition of the "response[...]" and ByteArrayOutputStream functionality, that it does not work.

Comment: OK. I'm getting confused now ;) Are you good now or not?

Comment: @g00se No problem, on the contrary!
The problem is still not solved, I tried and try again several manipulations in the code, but nothing makes it... I don't know where the problem can come from. It's driving me crazy!

Comment: I think you'd better update with your current code (which I hope incorporates the suggestions of @Anonyme)

Comment: Use debugger or logger or `System.out.println` to confirm what steps you've run. You don't say how you download via web interface, if via url double check you aren't caching old response url by appending trivial parameters (eg &xxx=yyy)

Comment: @g00se Here is the updated code. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Sorry I meant @DuncG not you ;). I can see you're *not* using all his suggestions. Write directly to the response, don't read into ```byte[]```  first. Also, I really want to see what's in that path list. Debugging info please

Comment: The list selectedFiles contains the full path to the searched file, i.e. from the root of the disk to the file extension ".csv". I just noticed, and I don't know why, that I end up with a duplicate path in this list... rather surprising!

Comment: *The list selectedFiles contains the full path to the searched file* (of which you are using the last element [the file name]) only as your entry. So if your list contains a/b/c/foo.csv and d/e/f/foo.csv, there will be a problem

Comment: The path to the file remains the same no matter what file you are looking for. Therefore, only the name of the file changes. I don't think the problem comes from that, because without going through ByteArrayOutputStream, it works. It's simply (it's nothing to say), the fact that we can choose in the browser, where we want to save this file... by the dialog box. Because by specifying the destination path of the "zip" file in the code, it works perfectly and my "zip" is complete.

Comment: *without going through ByteArrayOutputStream, it works.* We've been telling you to get rid of that all along

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand it that way. Oh... (I'm a beginner, sorry if I don't understand everything directly). What would I have to apply to my code to make it work? Thanks again ;) !